# Add day to empty database time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code

```
$Date = $db_date;
$ss = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + 1 days'));

$x = $con->prepare("UPDATE ssss SET ss=? WHERE sss=?");
$x->bind_param("ss", $ss, $sss);
$x->execute();
```

The code adds + 1 day to current database time if it's not empty, for example 2021-10-17, so it will be 2021-10-18. However, if the database time is empty (0000-00-00), it does nothing. I want to add +1 day to current day if the database time is empty.

Comment: DATEADD(Day, 1, ss) it will add one day .UPDATE ssss SET ss=DATEADD(Day, 1, ss) WHERE sss=?

Comment: Why would dbdate ever be empty? How do you populate it? Can't you just use an IF statement to check??

Comment: `0000-00-00` is not a valid date. Please correct this date in your database. Use NULL if there should be no date

Answer (score 0):

When the date is all zeroes, `now` can be used in the `strtotime` call as the current day:

```
$Date = $db_date;

if ($Date == '0000-00-00') {
    $ss = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now + 1 days'));
} else {
    $ss = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + 1 days'));
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://phpize.online/?phpses=cb15b8a26bc4607c57370e03a7e47d3b&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57) example with the date set to `0000-00-00`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using simple SQLquery:

```
UPDATE test SET sss = DATE_ADD(IFNULL(sss, CURDATE()), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

[Test it on SQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=6c3eff2f723c120581e6a1a96a36fd59&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)